# IOS delegates (such as "didEnterBackground") are not getting called on entering Background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

As in my application if  some action regarding "httpcall" are posted in the mainthread and my app is waiting for a response from server and same time home button is pressed than although app is entering background but IOS delegates (such as "didEnterBackground") are not getting called till the response are received.

Also sometime even if I'm relaunching the app its not responding till it gets crashed by itself.

Note:I'm using CyberLink code for my HTTP posts.

Comment: @Inder   All the HTTP calls in my project are Sync.Actually I want to close all those HTTP request on entering background.But issue is no delegate methods are getting called till it receives a response.

Comment: sync requests blocks the main thread that's why didEnterBackground is not being called. make them async.

Comment: @Inder  I tried with GCD now its working but still if u have some example code using GCD kindly share it.or if you know any link kindly share it

Comment: nope.... :( refer to any docs of apple

Answer (score 0):

As [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) :

> You should use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. You should also disable updates to your application’s user interface and avoid using some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts database)

I think you try to do something in background, for which `didEnterBackground` is not enough. Use [Grand Central Dispach](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) istead.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Http method are of synchronous type ..Your UI will froze till response.

What you have done is in simple words tell the OS to perform these http requests before doing anything else.

On pressing home the system will wait..for a few seconds to receive a response..otherwise it will quit thee app. since it violates app guidelines..(you are blocking OS indefinitely)

The didEnterBackground will be called only if these requests will be finished or will not be called in the case when OS decides to terminate your app.

Comment: send asynchronous http requests...that way they will be performed on background.. Your UI will not freeze and didEnterBackground will be called too

Comment: I tried with GCD now its working but still if u have some example code using GCD kidly share it.

Comment: i have not used GCD before... i have used ASIHTTPRequest...that is an easy way to do it for me..